# CheckMarx --> CxViewer -->scan issue

Tags: checkmarx, sts

I have a checkmarx issue when integrating it to SpringToolSuites, could you help me fix the issue please?, I am thinking that the origin of the issue is when I tried to authenticate to CheckMarx from STS
Could you please give me some help?

so when I run any Checkmarx scan from STS, I am getting this error:

"Scanner message: unexpected error occurred during login. Error details: failed to perform credentials login to server:"

Comment: Hi @sabrina, if it is a bug report, please report it to Checkmarx